# Is there a name for a property defined in terms of open sets?

Tags: general-topology, notation, definition

We know that if a property is defined in terms of open sets then the property is preserved under a homeomorphism. Is there a name for such a property?

Comment: a topological property/invariant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is called *topological invariant*. By definition, a topological invariant  is  is a property of a topological space which is invariant (i.e., preserved) under homeomorphisms, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142603/topological-invariants).

Comment: I think that is not quite what the OP is asking, although I could be wrong. For example, "cardinality of the underlying set" is a topological invariant which is not defined in terms of open sets. Properties of topological spaces defined only in terms of their open sets are properties of their underlying *locales* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointless_topology), so really should be called *localic properties*, I guess.